# How to prevent other mouse buttons from interrupting MouseMove?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, mouse, mouseevent

If you place a panel in a new C# project and capture it's MouseMove event like this:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine("e.X: {0}, e.Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
}
```

It tells you the client coordinates of the mouse while the left mouse button is held down, even if the cursor goes outside of the panel.

However, if you are holding down left mouse button in the container and then, while holding down left mouse button, click any other mouse button on your mouse, it no longer calls MouseMove while outside the bounds of the container.

Is there any way to change this? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1:** If you are trying to get it to work *only* when the left button is down, try the following:

```
bool mouseDown = false;

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!mouseDown)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine("e.X: {0}, e.Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
}

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        mouseDown = true;
}

private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        mouseDown = false;
}
```

**2:** Otherwise, if you want it to work when *any* mouse button is down, try the following:

```
int mouseDown = 0;

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDown == 0)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine("e.X: {0}, e.Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
}

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown++;
}

private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown--;
}
```

Comment: Don't have VS on my hands now to check, but this can lead to problem if you make a leftbuttondown, movemouse outside of the panel or application and release it there. Have doubts that panel1_MouseUp will be invoked. For this, should be enough to set the capture on control. See my edited post.

Comment: @Tigran, it does still trigger the event even outside of the bounds of the control.

Comment: you're right. I just checked it on another machine. I will edit my post. +1

Comment: Neither of these work. Click and hold left mouse button in the control. Click and release right mouse button while holing left mouse button. Move mouse outside the bounds of the panel and shake it there. No more console output at that point.

Comment: @John Smith agree: there is always a way to break something in this mechanism. I never found any secure way to resolve this kind of problems. I quoted this answer +1 only for the comment made. But, by the way it offers "a solution" that can be applied, and actually in some of my projects I use this trick.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Justin's solution will say that:

I think it's because, if during drag you go out of the panel right click *out* of the panel, forces  panel to lose the focus, so control no more becomes an active one.

In case of when you're dragging mouse inside panel and click with right click *inside* panel, happens something like this.

I just captured with Spy++ windows explorer and did a test, so moved the mouse with LButton down and at some point without releasing it made a right click. And here is a result:

With arrows I sign the row where I clicked with right button, where [WM_CAPTURECHANGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645605%28VS.85%29.aspx)
message sent. This message according to documentation is:

> Sent to the window that is losing the mouse capture.

Look on next line with arrow. The handle of the next window is 0, so there is no any window. So this means, like a simple command: You lost a capture on mouse.

Hope this helps.

[image: Screenshot of local test]

Comment: You don't actually need to reference API to solve the issue. See my answer for two examples.

Comment: @Justin: API is here to clarify why it happens. The rest you can see in my edited post.